# Any example for the multi-language website in Angular2 Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Any example for the multi-language website in Angular2 Dart?

In find a project in GitHub but it is a angular syntax.

https://github.com/technohippy/angular-translate.dart

Also, I cannot find any multi-language handling example on the tutorial website.
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/

Answer (score 0):

For AngularDart we use [`package:intl`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) for translation and internationalization. I don't think we have a tutorial for using `package:intl` in your Angular app, but it should just work if you use it as documented in the `package:intl` README.